# In Grails, how can I prevent duplicate list index entries when saving data in multiple threads?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, grails, grails-orm

I have a list of one domain object inside of another. There have been situations where two users will simultaneously update this list and the result is two of the same indexes in the table.  So, when I retrieve the domain object, one of the entries does not get added to the list.  For example:

**Domain Class 1**

```
class One {
    String stuff
    Integer blah
}
```

**Domain Class 2**

```
class Two {
    String description
    List<One> items
}
```

The resulting MySQL table ends up looking like:

```
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stuff                      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| blah                       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| items_idx                  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The items_idx seems to get duplicate entries in the scenario I described above.  So, for instance, it may end up looking like `1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6` Where the duplicate 4's are from two people adding to the list at the same time in two different threads.

Comment: If you don't want duplicate indexes it should be a `Set` instead of `List`

Comment: And, why not use [hasMany](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html) ?